# Non-sequential collection binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What is the best way to bind a dynamically created collection of elements in an MVC view to a collection in MVC 4. I know previous versions have required that the elements look like this:

```
<input name="Categories[0].CategoryID" type="hidden" value="123" />
<input name="Categories[0].CategoryName" type="hidden" value="Music" />
<input name="Categories[1].CategoryID" type="hidden" value="456" />
<input name="Categories[1].CategoryName" type="hidden" value="Movies" />
```

But when you are dynamically adding new elements and removing them, things get out of sequence pretty quickly.

Does **MVC 4** add a way to bind to a non-sequential collection?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Non sequential collection indices supported since MVC2 you just need to have a separate hidden field which will hold the index with the `name` schema: `CollectionName.Index`:

E.g:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Categories.Index" value="3" />
<input name="Categories[3].CategoryID" type="hidden" value="123" />
<input name="Categories[3].CategoryName" type="hidden" value="Music" />

<input type="hidden" name="Categories.Index" value="1" />
<input name="Categories[1].CategoryID" type="hidden" value="456" />
<input name="Categories[1].CategoryName" type="hidden" value="Movies" />
```

You can find more info about the topic here: [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't really appear to work well when using the Html Helpers, though, because you can't control the name of input elements using htmlAttributes.

Comment: No, there is no direct support for this with the `HtmlHelpers` but there are some third party helpers like [BeginCollectionItem helpers](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) which can generate the index hidden field and proper input names for you.

Comment: Bummer. I was hoping MVC4 would make this a little bit easier.