# Save DropDownListFor multiple selected values

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I save data for a multiple DropDownListFor? I have this code but the selected items aren't reaching the controller.

**My code view:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Ingredients, new SelectList(Model.ListIngredients, "Id", "Description"), "Select the ingredients", new { multiple = "multiple", })
```

**My model:**

```
public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
public ICollection<Ingredient> ListIngredients{ get; set; }
```

**Ingredient.cs:**

```
public string Description { get; set; }
public int Id { get; set; }
```

I have to change the name and id of my helper for data to be saved?

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/8434800/1126404

Comment: @NikolaMitev with a ListBoxFor it still don't working to me and with a ListBoxFor it's not possible to add a optionLabel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind the selected values into a collection of Ingredients. 
However if you take a look at the posted values, they will look something like this:

**...Ingredients=1&Ingredients=2...**

That means the model binder will not know how to convert values like 1,2 (which are the ingredient Ids) into instances of the ingredient class.

---

You need to change the property of your view model where you will get the ingredients selected by the user, so instead of a collection of Ingredients:

```
public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
```

you have a collection of Ids (which is the property you are using as the value of the multi-select), for example:

```
public int[] SelectedIngredients { get; set; }
```

(I have renamed the property but that is not strictly needed, I have done it just for clarity)

As a suggestion, I would remove the default option value from that multi-select (The "Select the ingredients" option) and use a label or tooltip. Otherwise it may look like any other value from the list and you will have to deal with the scenario where the user selects that option, which is not a valid ingredient.

Even better, I would also use the `@Model.ListBoxFor` helper as that will let everybody know they are dealing with a multi-select. Otherwise (with the drop down helper) you may not realize it is a multi-select unless you look at the attributes. Something like:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.SelectedIngredients, new SelectList(Model.ListIngredients, "Id", "Description"))
```

Of course, these are just suggestions. You can happily Ignore them if they don't apply to your requirements!

As a final comment, it is possible to convert the posted values into `Ingredient` objects as you initially had in your view model. That would require you to write your own model binder and configure it for the Ingredient type. However you will only receive the id in the posted values, so you would have to retrieve the other properties (from the database probably) or you will have a collection of Ingredient objects where only the Id is populated. I would not go down this route unless you really need to.

Comment: My boss don't want I use viewModel for this and it's other team that is responsable for the model and they need to have a collection of Ingredients (with Id and Description). I know it's possible to do what I want by only changing the name and (I suppose) the id of the helper. For example, I know the name must be something like `Name="Ingredients[]"`. But I tried with every names and ids (eg: `Name="Ingredients[].Id", id="Ingredients[]_Id"`) and nothing

Comment: I don't think you can do that unless you have a collection of simple types like int or string. The reason is that the select has a single name attribute so all the selected values will always be posted with that name. For what you want (a collection of complex objects) you need posted names like `Ingredients[0].Id`, `Ingredients[1].Id`. See [this link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) and [this link](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) for more info on the model binding with collections.

Comment: @Ninita, apart from that, you still have the option of creating your custom model binder

Comment: my boss has already said that it is unthinkable to do this because they have tried and failed

Comment: If you discard those options then you might need to consider alternative approaches like rendering a checkbox per ingredient. It would work with the name attribute of each checkbox being _Ingredients[XX].Id_ and its value the Id, as in `<input type="checkbox" name="Ingredients[0].Id" value="1"/>`. Because only checked ingredients will be posted, you will need to work around non-sequential posted indexes [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287203/non-sequential-collection-binding). You could wrap this in an EditorTemplate and do `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Ingredients)`