# Posting array of form fields with C# MVC BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a .NET MVC4 web application where I'm using jquery datatables to create a grid.

That grid holds about 100 users, but it only shows 5 users per page. In front of every user name I have a checkbox. I can select users from my grid and press the delete button to delete those users.

My table is build like this (simply put):

```
<table class="datatables">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[0].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[0].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[1].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[1].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[2].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[2].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[3].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[3].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[4].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[4].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Right now I can select the first two checkboxes and hit a Delete button to delete the selected records. The works fine. This will call an `ActionResult` which looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Delete(UserDeleteModel[] users)
{
    // delete records code
}
```

---

***BUT, *** when I navigate to the 2nd page in the datatables grid, then my table HTML will look like this:

```
<table class="datatables">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[5].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[5].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[6].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[6].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[7].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[7].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[8].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[8].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="user[9].Delete" /></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="user[9].Username" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the `input` fields start counting from `5`. Which makes sense of course.

But when I select a user and hit the Delete button then I do see that the browsers POSTS all the input fields and their values, but the `ActionResult` gives me an empty `UserDeleteModel[] list`.

The reason why `UserDeleteModel[] list` is `NULL` is because the form fields in the table grid don't start counting from `0` on page two. It starts from `5` on the second page.

For some reason .NET MUST have fields that start from `0` counting upwards in order. If it starts from any other number then the posted fields aren't mapped to my ViewModel in the controller.

I do see the form values in the `Request.Form` object. But for reason it's not being mapped.

This is a problematic bug of course. Anyone any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: if you are using jquery datatable means,why you can simply delete the selected item in script itself.

Comment: Have you tried initialising the array in the controller action, then using `TryUpdateModel`?

Comment: @AdrianWragg Just tried it, no luck though. Did it like this: `list = new UserDeleteModel[5];` `TryUpdateModel(list);`. Or even: `TryUpdateModel(Request.Form)`. I can see that the values are there in `Request.Form`. It just doesn't map things..

Comment: @Vivendi Try `[10]` instead, in case it'll only populate indexes 5 to 9? There's a chance you might also have to try `TryUpdateModel(list, "user");`

Comment: @AdrianWragg Tried as you suggested. No luck unfortunately. All keys remain `null` in the array.

Comment: @Vivendi *Very* much a hack, but what happens if you pass through a dummy value for `user[0].Delete` if it's not on-screen?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287203/non-sequential-collection-binding

Comment: @Floremin Thanks, that fixed my problem. So when working with arbitrary indices then .NET needs an (hidden) input field with the `Index` suffix holding the key as value. Could you please post your comment as an answer so I have something to accept :)

Comment: @Floremin Very neat solution, good find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is in how ASP.NET MVC binds collections. You are posting a non-sequential collection (i.e. index does not start with at 0), so the default MVC binder does not know how to resolve.

Take a look at the following answer:

[Non-sequential collection binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287203/non-sequential-collection-binding)

Other solution would be to create your own binder, depending on your needs.