# Official documentation for non sequential indices model binding

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC you can have a hidden field With field.index to specify the ids to use for non sequential indices for model binding.

For example see this post
[Non-sequential collection binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287203/non-sequential-collection-binding)

Is it an officially documented feature? Or is it undocumented?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/