# ASP MVC passing non-sequential items

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view model containing `public List<Room> Rooms { get; set; }` Rooms contains a `List<BL.Image> Images`. In my view I loop through the room and display each image.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count; i++)
{
    @for (var ii = 0; ii < Model.Rooms[i].Images.Count; ii++)
    {
        <div class="slide">
            <img class="pic panel" src="@Url.Content(Model.Rooms[i].Images.ToList()[ii].Path)" />
            @{ ViewBag.Imageindex = "Rooms[" + i + "].Images[" + ii + "].Index"; }
            <input type="hidden" name="@ViewBag.ImageIndex" value="@Html.Raw(ii)" />
@*also tried<input type="hidden" name="@ViewBag.ImageIndex" value="" />also tried*@

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Images.ToList()[ii].ImageID, new { Name = "Rooms[" + i + "].Images[" + ii + "].ImageID" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Images.ToList()[ii].Path, new { Name = "Rooms[" + i + "].Images[" + ii + "].Path" })
            <div class="snipit">
                <img class="hoverpic panel" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/99/office/128/delete.png" width="40" height="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Images can be added or deleted by the user but if an image gets deleted, when the form is submitted only images before the deleted images are recognised e.g.

- image 1, image 2, image 3, image 4 are displayed
- image 3 get deleted
- when the form is submitted only images 1 and 2 are recognised.

One of the questioned I reviewed to solve this issue was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287203/non-sequential-collection-binding) and I seem to be doing the same thing. The question also links to a [Blog Post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) in this - near the end it covers non-sequential indices

> **Non-Sequential Indices**
>   ... what happens when you can’t guarantee that the submitted values will maintain a sequential index? For example, suppose you want to allow deleting rows before submitting a list of books via JavaScript.
>   The good news is that by introducing an extra hidden input, you can allow for arbitrary indices. In the example below, we provide a hidden input with the .Index suffix for each item we need to bind to the list. The name of each of these hidden inputs are the same ... this will give the model binder a nice collection of indices to look for when binding to the list.

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

<input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
<input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
<input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />

<input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
<input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />

<input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
<input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
<input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />

<input type="submit" />
```

> Unfortunately, we don’t have a helper for generating these hidden inputs.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 hidden inputs for the collection indexers with names `Rooms.Index` and `Rooms[i].Images.Index`. In addition, do not attempt to change the `name` attributes generated by the `HtmlHelper` methods. Your code should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Rooms.Count; i++)
{
    <input type="hidden" name="Rooms.Index" value="@i" /> // outer indexer
    @for (var ii = 0; ii < Model.Rooms[i].Images.Count; ii++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="Rooms[@i].Images.Index" value="@ii" /> // inner indexer
        <div class="slide">
            <img class="pic panel" src="@Url.Content(Model.Rooms[i].Images.ToList()[ii].Path)" />
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Images[ii].ImageID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Rooms[i].Images[ii].Path)
            <div class="snipit">
                <img class="hoverpic panel" src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/99/office/128/delete.png" width="40" height="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has worked (very relieved). In regards to not changing the name element I only did so as a last resort. Prior to changing it `name="[4].Path"` was being rendered (for example) and images were being passed as null. Could I be doing something wrong further up the chain, or does that question require a new thread?

Comment: Just noticed you had `.ToList()` in there which needs to be removed (see edit)

Comment: Sorry, I put `List<Image>` it should be `ICollection`, hence indexing not being applied without converting it to a list. The `Room` class is generated by entity framework so I think i'm stuck with it being a collection, i think

Comment: Your editing data, so always use a view model :) - and the view model will contain collection properties which are `List<T>`, and use `.ToList()` in the GET method when mapping the data model to the view model.

Comment: Thanks, I am using a view model and i'm embarrassed that i never considered converting it at that point